# java applet not caching with 1.6 update 24 and IE/Chrome

Tags: java, caching, applet

I have a fairly large applet that I want to be cached between browser restarts.

I have set the cache_archive and cache_version tags, as well as the cache_ex tag.
cache_ex tag uses jar version to determine cache invalidation.

If the client is running latest java (1.7 update 40), then I see from the IIS web logs that there are no http gets of the jars when I restart the browser and load the applet.

With java 1.6 update 24, there are http gets.

I am forced to use this ancient version 1.6 of java because of company idiocy.

How can I get this working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, here are my settings (I am using JavaScript to load applet)

```
cache_option: "Plugin",
cache_archive: "RELATIVE/PATH/TO/JAR#1,RELATIVE/PATH/TO/JAR#2, etc.",
cache_version: "JAR#1-VERSION, JAR#2-VERSION, etc.",
cache_archive_ex: "JAR#1;preload;JAR#1-VERSION, JAR#2;preload;JAR#2-VERSION, etc.  ",
```

Important: jars that you want in the sticky cache should not be in the archive tag.

thanks.